# http_addition_module Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I'm having trouble with the this module, it keeps telling me 404 not found,

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain.com;
    location / {
        add_before_body $document_root/test.txt;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass http://IP/;
    }
}
```

in document root is the file, it's defiantly there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mentioned root directive in your config file? It sets the directory for your requests. Nginx appends `$uri` to this directory and will serve the file.

```
server{
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain.com;

    #e.g 
    root /var/www; #" the directory where test.txt exists.
    location /{
        add_before_body test.txt;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass http://IP/;
    }
}
```

See more 
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root